# Yii2 dropDownList disable only in create mode

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii2

I am doing it like this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'HRMS_candidateStatus')->dropDownList($candidateStatus, [ 'prompt' => 'Select candidate status','class'=>'form-control input-sm',['disabled' => $model->isNewRecord] ]) ?>
```

I want the dropdown list to be disabled on create mode only. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Disabled Html as condition

```
<?= $form->field($model,   'HRMS_candidateStatus')->
 dropDownList($candidateStatus, [ 'prompt' => 'Select candidate status','class'=>'form-control input-sm',
['disabled' => ($model->isNewRecord) ? 'disabled' : false] ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `true` or `disabled` and `false`:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'HRMS_candidateStatus')->dropDownList($candidateStatus, [ 'prompt' => 'Select candidate status','class'=>'form-control input-sm',
'disabled' => $model->isNewRecord ? true : false ]) ?>
```